# In Dekker's and Brent's Method, in the initial steps, it states that $a$ and $b$ must be swapped if $|f(a)| < |f(b)|$, why is this step being done?

Tags: numerical-methods

In Dekker's and Brent's method, in the initial steps, if $|f(a)|<|f(b)|$, we swap $a$ and $b$.

Why is this?

I've searched for reasons why, but I cannot find a reason why.

- [Cleve Moler](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2015/10/12/zeroin-part-1-dekkers-algorithm/) mentions:

> $b$ is the best zero so far, in the sense that $f(b)$ is the smallest value of $f(x)$ so far.

- [Oscar Veliz](https://youtu.be/-bLSRiokgFk?t=171) (2:51) mentions that it is to keep $b$ as the "better" guess.

But I cannot find an explanation as to why this is.

Comment: I don’t know much about the method, but if your rationale is “get as close to zero as possibile”, then this step is apparently “in the correct direction”. Of course this is not always the case, as various counterexample show.

Answer (score 1):

Because the convention in Dekkers description of the algorithm (but not Wikipedia's Dekker-Brent method article), the loop invariant if you want, is that there are 3 points $a,b,c$ that represent the current state (Brent's method has 4 points, 3 points for inverse quadratic interpolation and one bracketing counter-point):

- the points $a,b$ are the source for the next secant root computation,
- the interval between $b$ and $c$ is the root-bracketing interval and
- $b$ is the point with the current smallest function value.

This loop convention avoids additional logic inside the loop, reduces the cases to consider.

In Dekker's method, the pair of $a$ and $b$ usually contains the last two iterates of the secant method. This sequence of course gets broken if some non-secant step (midpoint or minimal step) was taken.

Given a bracketing interval $[a,b]$, the actual first step of Dekker's method is to assign $c=a$. After that the values at $b,c$ are compared as first step in the loop.

In a "normal" step, when $a,b$ are close to the root inside $[b,c]$ and  the function looks almost linear at that "zoom level", the value at the secant root $s$ computed from $a$ and $b$ can be expected to be closer to $b$ than the midpoint $m=\frac12(b+c)$ and to be the new smallest value, esp. $|f(s)|<|f(b)|<|f(a)|$.

If these assumptions fail, then the midpoint and the secant root computed from $b,c$ are perhaps better candidates for the next iteration point $x$ (remember that only the evaluation of $f$ is "costly", all other computations count as "free").

This is almost surely the case when (at the start of the loop) $|f(c)|<|f(b)|<|f(a)|$ (the latter because of the previous step). In that case, the comparison in question at the start of the loop sets $a,b,c = b,c,b$, so it not only swaps $b,c$ in the bracketing interval, but also sets up that the next secant root is computed from the bracketing interval à la regula falsi.

(*Here the answer ends, for completeness I add the remaining steps of the algorithm*)

If even with these precautions the secant root falls outside $[b,m]$, then the midpoint $m$ is chosen as next point $x$, or a minimal step to get out of numerically ambiguous situations like a double root.

With now $b<x\le m < c$ the state is shifted to $a,b,c = b,x,c$.
As the last act inside the loop, if $[b,c]$ is no longer a bracketing interval, the counter-point $c$ is set to $a$ so that the signs of the function values are again opposite.